# White screen after presenting a modal view controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I'm getting a white screen after presenting a modal view controller. This is how I do it:

```
SomeViewController *controller = [[[SomeViewController alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext] autorelease];
UINavigationController *navController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller] autorelease];
[navController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
[self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
```

The navigation bar works fine, as I set it up in SomeViewController, but the view's contents are not visible, and all I see is the white background color of the root window.

The strange thing is, that this used to work, but now it doesn't for some reason.
What could be the problem?

**EDIT:**

This is how I create SomeViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self setTitle:@"Some View"];

    UIBarButtonItem *sortButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sort" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(sortButtonClicked:)] autorelease];
    [[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortButton, [self editButtonItem], nil] animated:YES];

    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:)] autorelease];
    [[self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:backButton];

    // Hack to force landscape orientation
    UIViewController *controller = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:NO];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [controller release];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

Comment: Use breakpoints to see if `SomeViewController *controller` has memory or not.

Comment: It does get assigned with a proper memory address. In fact, the view controllers' methods get called properly(viewDidLoad, etc.).

Comment: Ok. Could you post some code for how you create `SomeViewController`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The white screen was caused by the `xib file` of the controller not being part of the `target`(its target membership checkbox was unchecked).

Answer (score 0):

Do you happen to have some other init meted also in the SomeViewController class? Please post the whole .m file. If so, you can try to delete the initWithNibName method and check if it shows the content.

EDIT:
Another strange point is the initWithManagedObjectContext method you are using on the viewController instance. Can you explain it?

Comment: I don't have any other init methods defined. Even with the default init(not overridden), it doesn't work.

Comment: I've changed `initWithManagedObjectContext` to the default `init`. It doesn't cause the problem.

Comment: Are the methods in the .m of SomeViewController the only ones that you have or there is also something else inside?

Answer (score -1):

try

```
SomeViewController *controller = [[[SomeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
```

it should work fine.

Comment: It does not. The view's contents are still not visible.

Comment: remove autorelease for both SomeViewController and navigation controller